# Is there any use in writing $≫ 0$ or $≪ \infty$?

Tags: inequality, infinity

Is there any use in writing $x ≫ 0$ (or $x ≪ \infty$)?

Of course, $x > 0$ (or $x < \infty$) makes sense, and $x ≫ a$ (or $x ≪ a$) makes sense when $a \neq$ 0 (or $a \neq \infty$). I usually interpret this as $x/a ≫ 1$ (or $x/a ≪ 1$) rather than $x - a ≫ 0$ (or $x - a ≪ 0$). But this interpretation fails with those special values of $a$.

Comment: From what I know $\gg$ means "much larger", so it might be of use when we mean something along the lines "for $x$ larger than some fixed but unspecified constant".

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen $x<<\infty$ since that doesn't seem to mean much to me, though $x < \infty$ is a common paraphrasing of "$x$ finite"

Comment: @Wojowu I like your idea with that "unspecified constant". But then again, in **math** - why not specify it? :)

Comment: @bers Because sometimes nonconstructive proofs don't yield an explicit constant :(

Comment: @Wojowu do you happen to have an example? I still wonder how $>>$ can be exact enough then.